# Angular Material mat-table data not refreshed from parent changes

Tags: angular-material2

I am using in a component a `mat-table` with a `MatTableDataSource` and I want to set up the data from its parent component but data are not refreshed at screen whereas child component well detects data changes...

**Child component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-person-list',
  template: `
    <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let person">{{ person.name }}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="age">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Age </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let person">{{ person.age }}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
  `
})
export class PersonListComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() data: Person[];

  displayedColumns = ['name', 'age'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Person>();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.data = this.data;
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes) {
    console.log('Data changed', this.data);
  }
}
```

**Parent component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `<app-person-list [data]="personList"></app-person-list>`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  personList: Person[] = [];

  constructor(private service: PersonService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getPersonList().subscribe(res => this.personList.push(...res));
  }
}
```

[Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/zZIZ1y/)

Does someone knows why the table is not updated when data changes ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you find any solution for it. I have similar problem please help me if you have solution.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're calling `this.dataSource.data = this.data;` only on ngOnInit, which means that you aren't doing anything with the updated data.

I created a pipe just for this, and so that I wouldn't have to use MatTableDataSource everywhere -

```
@Pipe({
   name: 'dataSource'
})
export class DataSourcePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(array: any[]): any {
    return array ? new MatTableDataSource(array) : new MatTableDataSource([]);
  }
}
```

Using it like this `$data | dataSource` in the template

That way your data is always up to date and you don't have to use MatTableDataSource manually.

EDIT:
You can still use filter and sort functionalities when using this.

You're giving data to the component and then using MatTableDataSource to wrap it. Instead you can do it like this - `<component [data]="$array | async | dataSource"></component>` where $array is an observable.

And then inside the component - `<mat-table [dataSource]="data"></mat-table>`

This way you can just manipulate the data object, without having to wrap it in the MatTableDataSource inside the component.

Comment: Seems to be nice but I want to keep control of the datasource to use its functionalities (sort, filter).

Comment: In the parent component you use the pipe, for example <component data="$array | async | dataSource"></component> where $array is an observable. And inside the component, you use @Input() data; So you can do whatever you want with it, retaining the sort, filter and everything else.   The reason why this works, is because it is still a MatTableDataSource object inside of the component in the end.

Comment: If I well understand, to use this pipe, the input has to be directly a MatTableDataSource and no more a Person[].

Comment: Yep, although I don't see how that is a problem? You use the MatTableDataSource directly anyway for all kinds of actions, e.g. sort and filter. And if you want to access the Persons[] inside of it, you use data.data

Comment: @IvarKallejärv do you have any example on how to use pagination and sorting?
I tried it "as usually" inside child component but it is just not being attached to the data at all

Answer (score 3):

The only way I found is to change the reference of the array and reassign it...

**Child component**

```
@Component( [...] )
export class PersonListComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() data: Person[];

  displayedColumns = ['name', 'age'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Person>();

  ngOnChanges(changes) {
    this.dataSource.data = this.data;
  }
}
```

**Parent component**

```
@Component( [...] )
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  personList: Person[] = [];

  constructor(private service: PersonService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getPersonList().subscribe(res => {
      if (this.personList.length > 0) {
        res.unshift(this.personList);
      }
      this.personList = res;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I use this solution, but once I use ngOnChanges and assign new data to my dataSource i have terrible performance issues! I have 500 rows and this way rendering of the table takes 10-20 sec. Any other way like fetching the data from the table component just for testing will render the table in less than a sec. Did you encounter such issue?